# Python subprocess another python script not producing output

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, output

I have a simple python3 script `test.py`:

```
print('Test')

while True:
    inp = input('> ')
    print(input)
```

When I try to run it with `subprocess.Popen` and get its output, it freezes:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['python3', 'test.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False)
print(p.stdout.read())
```

So, I'm not getting any output from that script. I tried using `communicate`  and somehow it worked:

```
p.communicate()[0]
```

But I still need to make piped stdout work. What's wrong with the first example of getting output from my script?

UPD: `communicate` shows there's an exception in `test.py`: EOF on `input` on line 4. Why? How can I interact with such script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't feeding stdin any input, so you naturally get an `EOFError` at line 4, which is the exception raised when `input` reaches EOF. But even if you feed it some input, since it has an infinite loop, it will eventually consume all input and end up raising `EOFError`. You should catch the exception and end the script gracefully.

Also, you have a typo at line 5, where you want it to print `inp`, not `input`.

Finally, you should always use `communicate` instead of reading directly from `stdout` or writing directly to `stdin`.

From [Popen's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr):

> **Warning:** Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Corrected `test.py`:

```
print('Test')

while True:
    try:
        inp = input('> ')
    except EOFError:
        print 'Done'
        break
    print(inp)
```

The right way to interact with `test.py`:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> p = Popen(['python', 'test.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False)
>>> p.communicate('hello\nworld\n')
('Test\n> hello\n> world\n> Done\n', '')
>>>
```